# Eclipse Debugger shows a different value for a final field than the source code does

Tags: java, eclipse, debugging, maven, testng

while trying to solve an OutOfMemoryError when starting a TestNG-suite, I changed my pom.xml to use the latest version currently available: TestNG 6.8.7 (before: 6.8.1)

But if I'm trying to start a suite now, org.testng.internal.Version.displayBanner() still prints the same text:

```
...
... TestNG 6.8.6beta_20130517_2142 by Cédric Beust (cedric@beust.com)
...
```

I have two problems with this text: according to my pom, it should be 6.8.7, not 6.8.6beta_...
And according to the source Eclipse has downloaded, it should be "6.8.2beta_20130330_0839".
When debugging org.testng.internal.Version.displayBanner, Eclipse behave odd, in my opinion - I've made a screenshot: [Eclipse showing different text in source than in output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4drz3.png)

On other workstations than mine, the printed text is different, but not the intended version 6.8.7: "TestNG 6.8.6 by Cédric Beust" too.

I can't find TestNG 6.8.6beta_... in my classpath.

My question is:
why is the String of the version different in source, printed/during runtime and why are both versions not equal to 6.8.7?!

Edit: Sorry, screenshot wasn't captured whily debugging. The new screenshot is linked above, the old can be found here: [not at runtime: Eclipse showing different text in source than in output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHnRJ.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found part of the problem by myself. I updated Eclipse's TestNG-plugin, now TestNG 6.8.6 is printed. Seems that the used version in pom.xml isn't relevant for execution with Eclipse - could have known that.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it is still not well understood that it is not a good idea to put version information into a `public static final` field. If such a field has a primitive type or `String` and is directly assigned like in this example, it’s a compile-time constant and every class referring that field will copy its value at compile time. So inconsistencies are very likely if the version at compile time is different than the version at runtime.

Further, eclipse does not necessarily show the correct source code version of a class. Depending of the type of the library there are different ways how source files are associated with binary class files but Eclipse will not verify whether the source file and class file are compatible.

If in doubt whether the currently executed class is the right version, you can verify the source of the class in the debugger. Go to the “Expressions” view and add a new entry `org.testng.internal.Version.class.getProtectionDomain().getCodeSource().getLocation()`. That’s pretty long but thankfully there’s copy&paste. This works for all classes not from the JRE. An alternative is `org.testng.internal.Version.class.getResource("Version.class")` which works even for JRE classes but requires some interpretation of the result. You can use the short class names if the class currently shown in the debugger imports the class.

Well, you have solved the problem already but I think such things are good to know for the next time…